# Enable "Print background colors and images" for all users with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, registry

In the context of a project, I have to succeed, with a code in PowerShell, to activate the "Print background colors and images" parameter for all users.
For the moment, I can activate it for the current user with the following command:

`Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HCKU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup\' _Name 'Print_Background' -Value YES _Force`

Unfortunately, and logically, this only affects the current user and not all other users as desired.

I'm still not very comfortable with registry keys. I understand that I have to use a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. But I haven't figured out how to access this parameter using such a key. I tried to replace 'HKCU' by 'HKLM', as recommended by some people, but it returns me an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable the option **Print background colors and images** in the page setup of the IE browser for all users then you need to create registry on location below.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet
> Explorer\Main

Name: Print_Background

Value: yes

You can try to modify your script and try to check whether it works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately, I tried it and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please try to explain what exactly did not work? Did you get any error? If possible try to first manually set the registry and check whether it works in ie browser then after trying with your script.